# How to remove the unverified server popup in AIR?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm developing a mobile app in flex using Flash Builder 4.6.
This application accesses a WSDL webservice using HTTPS.
The server has a valid commercial certificate, but whenever I try to access the webservice for the first time in each session, AIR displays the question "The server that the application is connecting to is unverified." if I check "Trust for Session" everything works correctly.

I want to know how can I remove this warning?

Comment: "The server has a valid commercial license" for what?  Where does your AIR app display that message?  I'm unclear if you're asking a question about a server configuration issue or something else.

Comment: I meant that the server has a valid certificate. It was a mistake when I wrote license

I'll edit the question to correct it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: Did someone find an answer to this question?

Comment: Did someone find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stopped happening after updating the version of Android and Adobe Air